# Is there a way to determine which button was clicked in out-gridview?

Tags: powershell

I have the following in my ps1 script, I want to take a specific action if the person presses [OK] opposed to [CANCEL] in Out-Gridview gui. Any way to do this?

```
$DataResults  | Out-GridView -Title $Title -PassThru | clip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the person pressed OK then there should be output so, you can assign the output to a variable and then check if its not `$null`.

```bash
$selection = $DataResults | Out-GridView -Title $Title -PassThru
if($null -ne $selection) {
    # user pressed OK, do stuff here
    $selection | Set-Clipboard
}
```